# Merge tags [dds] with [data-distribution-service]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Both [dds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dds) and [data-distribution-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-distribution-service) appear to refer to the same thing. Could someone with the power please review this and merge these tags to make searching for this simpler and less divided?

Comment: FYI, a synonym has been suggested.  http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dds/synonyms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went through the questions tagged [dds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dds) and found they were unambiguously refering to the Data Distribution Service. I untagged some dubious uses of the tag, and closed some obviously off-topic questions.

Some confusion arose from the [rti-dds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rti-dds) wiki mentioning some Domain Distribution Service, which appears to not be a thing. I adjusted the tag wiki accordingly.

[dds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dds) was made a synonym of [data-distribution-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-distribution-service), I will perform the actual merge tomorrow.